# Can a mac running ubuntu use GPU?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, nvidia

I am making a research before getting a MacBook.

I want to know if I can use GPU (AMD's) in Linux running on a Mac natively.

I really appreciate it if someone could help. Because I will need to use some ML tools that use GPU.

Regards,

Thiago

Comment: The latest M1 Macs cannot boot anything other than MacOS natively, and while there are efforts to get M1 booting Linux, drivers are a long way off, if ever. However, if you get an Intel machine, and you boot Linux on it natively, you should have full access to all of the hardware just as you would on any other Intel-based Linux machine. While I don't have a Mac with a discrete GPU to actually test it, I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to access the GPU from within Linux as long as you're using an Intel Mac and are running Linux natively (i.e. not in a VM).

Comment: Why get a macbook for running Linux and ML tools if you can get a normal laptop with better hardware in a similar price range?

Comment: Hi @fdmillion, thanks for your answer. I will have an Intel-based Mac. I'm happy to know that it will work. I will use tools like Tensorflow, PyTorch, etc. I was looking at AMD's website and they support tools like that, so it won't have a problem running it.

Comment: @Loupeznik Because I will need some MacOS tools too, to do other things.